# Is there a way to get updated badge counter from QuickBlox in iOS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, quickblox

I'm successfully getting push notifications for chats which are send by `QuickBlox` it self. However there's certain cases where I'm sending push notifications to other users in code too. At this point, I lost my self in sea !

Another user who's currently logged-out, so the app is showing 5 in badge counter (for unread chats).. then if I send him a push via code it should increase to 6 ... but its not updating. How do I pass 6 in `QBMPushMessageBadgeKey` with push I'm sending in code.

Please help me in figuring this out !! This will gonna a big issue in QuickBlox.

Answer (score 0):

For sending push notifications you can use

```
+ (QBRequest *)createEvent:(QBMEvent *)event successBlock:(void (^)(QBResponse *, NSArray *))successBlock
            errorBlock:(QBRequestErrorBlock)errorBlock;
```

and the simplest way is to use:

```
+ (QBRequest *)sendPush:(QBMPushMessage *)pushMessage toUsers:(NSString *)usersIDs successBlock:(void(^)(QBResponse *response, QBMEvent *event))successBlock errorBlock:(void (^)(QBError *error))errorBlock
```